# Tesseract returns non English characters

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I recently followed some tutorials to setup Tesseract and now I am trying to see if the OCR is working properly. When I take a picture and get the text I am sometimes getting Non English characters. It actually seems like gibberish. I have posted an example of an output I got below:

```
 ; .'—--~_~:~ ear
 .::§—‘.::~__>‘Z~r'.‘ ,::-SES‘:3£a"3'§_“5.E.~ °?®.=_-
 .—_;%~‘=*c§u-5; H =—oc+-»o cn-5 '55:.
```

The picture I took was the first page from the research article in [this](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en/us/pubs/archive/40749.pdf) link. I'm not sure why this is happening. I have the eng.traineddata file within the tessdata sub directory as well.

Answer (score 1):

there are two things that come to my mind:

- train tesseract for the font that is used in the image
- edit the image beforehand

  - grayscale
  - resize
  - dilate
  - smoothing
  - gaussian blur
  - ... and so on

For the editing I can recommend [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).